# How to add dates to calender in the right way

Tags: android, datetime, kotlin, calendar, java.util.calendar

I have an ArrayList that contains date - `[1, 5, 2020] // day|month|year`

I am adding this to calendar in this way:

```
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dateList[0])
calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, dateList[1])
calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, dateList[2])
```

But when I try to assign this to my date picker, I am getting this date:

```
datePicker.maxDate = calendar
date picker Log: 16/10/4040
```

What could be the problem with my code?

Comment: Kotlin + outdated and troublesome datetime API = no good idea... Use `java.time` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you **ADD** those values (to the initial date when it was instantiated). Instead you should use **set**.

```
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dateList[0])
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, dateList[1])
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, dateList[2])
```

Answer (score 2):

Modern answer. Valid in Java since 2014, I think it came to Android a few years later.

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

I Java because this is what I can write.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> dateList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 5, 2020));

    LocalDate date = LocalDate
            .of(dateList.get(2), dateList.get(1), dateList.get(0));

    System.out.println("Date: " + date);
```

Output is:

> Date: 2020-05-01

`LocalDate` (opposite `Calendar`) numbers months sanely, so 5 is May. If you intended June, don’t use the literal 5, it would be very confusing. If you cannot use 6 for June, use the built-in constant `Calendar.JUNE`. And remember to add 1 when passing to `LocalDate.of()`.

Since you need the date as a `Calendar` object for your date picker, we need to convert. A `Calendar` object includes time of day and time zone and more, so is really overkill, but we need to obey the date picker API, of course. It’s conventional to use the start of the day in the JVM’s time zone.

```
    ZonedDateTime startOfDay = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    Calendar oldfashionedCalendar = DateTimeUtils.toGregorianCalendar(startOfDay);

    System.out.println(oldfashionedCalendar.getTime());
```

> Fri May 01 00:00:00 CEST 2020

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in. Only in this case don’t use `DateTimeUtils` for the conversion, use the slightly simpler `GregorianCalendar.from(startOfDay)`.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

> `calender.add` function makes addition with your current date use 
>   `calender.set` it will set date.